Can not use multiple C++ files in Swift Package
I want to build a swift package which also uses code from c++ , so the problem I am facing is I can build and use one single c++ file , but when I add multiple c++ file it shows file not found. As the screenshot describes this more.
My swift package file -
// swift-tools-version: 5.10
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "AVTPG_Module",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "AVTPG_Module",
            targets: ["AVTPG_Module"]
        ),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        .target(
            name: "CppModule",
            path: "Sources/CppModule",
            cxxSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("include")
            ]
        ), // <- Add a comma here
        .target(
            name: "AVTPG_Module",
            dependencies: ["CppModule"],
            swiftSettings: [.interoperabilityMode(.Cxx)]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "AVTPG_ModuleTests",
            dependencies: ["AVTPG_Module"]
            
        ),
    ]
)


Screenshot -

I want to use multiple c++ file in my swift package.
